# Python on Heroku - Sending to a background worker

Tags: python, heroku, queue

I have a long-running task currently running as a web process on Heroku which according to Heroku docs I need to move to a background worker to avoid timeouts.

How does the web process actually connect to the background worker both to give it the work and to pick up the results? The heroku [docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python#running_a_worker) don't seem to explain this.

Answer (score 3):

Its more a question of how you commonly do this in Python. The docs have further detail around how to do this with Django, though the key piece is doing this within Celery. You can find more info at: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#running_a_worker

Comment: This link is outdated as of 2014

Comment: Here an updated link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq and a related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733050/heroku-background-tasks-in-python-with-rq)